# Specifying a complement to std::to_string()?

Tags: c++, c++11

In C++11, since there is a standard [std::to_string()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string), I overload this function for enumeration classes and other small data classes where an implementation makes sense.

My question is, what do you implement as a complement to `std::to_string()`?

Some kind of `from_string()` (which doesn't exist in std) or is there a more appropriate standard interface you implement throughout your classes?

Comment: In C++03 one would overload operators `<<` and `>>`, so that string conversions could performed with stringstreams (boost::lexical_cast).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the standard using uses the terse naming scheme used in old C. so where you have

```
std::string to_string( int value );
```

you have

```
int std::stoi(std::string);
```

see here

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol

so where you might have.

```
std::string to_string(my_enum);
```

you might have

```
my_enum stomy_enum(std::string)
```

although I would just be verbose about it

```
my_enum string_to_my_enum(std::string)
```

or just use streams

```
std::stringstream ss(my_str);
if(ss >> emun_) //conversion worked
```

Defining stream operator also allows to use lexical cast from boost;

```
enum_ = boost::lexical_cast<my_enum>(my_str);
```

Comment: Not only is it more verbose (and generally unreadable), it’s also not polymorphic and thus doesn’t work with generics. Bad solution. A better solution would use overloading either with the overload-on-return-type-trick via implicit conversions, or explicitly specified templates, or output parameters (but I don’t like the latter).

Comment: I you should be careful defining implicit conversions for types (especially enums types) that can make some very hard to read code. It is ungeneric but so is stoi(). Streams are a good idea here (for generic code) as both the standard and custom type generally have them defined.

Comment: I was under the impression that `std::stoi` and friends were just C++ wrappers on the C library `atoi` functions. I think what he's looking for is more along the lines of insertion and extraction operators for his user defined objects.

Comment: AJG85: I don't know whether or not stoi just wrap the C buffer implementations or implements them, but they are indeed inline with the old C style versions. The stream operators are the way to go, I think if you having to do a lot of type conversion your design might be off.

Comment: @111111 The implicit conversion in this particular case is harmless, because it will trigger exactly what the user wants, and never anything else. It essentially just allows overloading of methods based on return type. This is fundamentally a same operation, in the same way that input streaming is.

Comment: Konrad, but every one know the streaming idiom, I don't think people want PHP everything is compatible code in C++. That is just my gut feeling.

Answer (score 0):

C++11 has `stoi`, `stol`, `stod`, etc for arithmetic types.

Comment: If it was just for arithmetic types, you could of course also just use `std::atoi(s.c_str())` (or `std::atol` or `std::atof`) which has been around forever to achieve the same effect with C++03.

Answer (score 0):

If your type is a class a constructor taking a string as argument would make more sense then a free function to me.

Comment: This depends whether your type needs to have a notion of strings. for example you would want a vector to be initialised off a CSV in a string even if that was a useful function.

Comment: @111111 I assume that there is a negation missing in your example. Of course a constructor from string is only meaningful if the type is in some "natural" way expressible as a string. This should go without saying.

Answer (score 0):

The C++11 standardlibrary has only `stoi` et al. for this as far as I know. However if you are ok with using boost (which I'd say is a quasi standard library for c++) you can use [`boost::lexical_cast`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html). For that to work you just need to define the stream operators `operator>>` respectively `operator<<` (for conversion to string) for `std::istream` (`std::ostream`) for your own classes.

When not using `boost` I would still use stream operatos for this, so to get an int from a string I'd do something like the following:

```
std::string s = ...;
int i;
std::stringstream stream(s);
stream>>i;
```

Of course you can put that into a more generic function, which will give you functionality similar to `boost::lexical_cast`.

Comment: I agree type conversion should be suitable infrequent for performance to take a back seat of readability. A good all-round would be good for the next standard.